# pass variable across multiple controllers in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have two controllers namely user and calendar. I have to pass user object from the user to calendar. How can we pass variable across multiple controller in sails?

Comment: What do you actually mean, passing variables from a controller to another? Why can't you simply call your model inside your controller. Or you can create a service in /api/services and call it globally. If you give me more details I will certainly have an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting with sails (and node.js generally speaking), but I'm fearly common with javascript (client sided).

The only way I found out was using the variable scope. If you declare a variable before any anonymous function, you'll be able to edit this variable from inside the function. So inside your action in your controller you'll have something like :

```
        //this will allow me to store my informations inside the categories variable.
        var categories;
        Categories.find().done(function(err, cat){
            categories = cat;
        });

        //calling another datas and passing them to the view, alongside with my previous datas
        Categories.findOne(id).done( function(err, cat){
            return res.view({
                data : cat,
                cats : categories
            });
        })
```

I'm sure they're a lot of better ways, and I'm interested in knowing them =)

Comment: tried this and watched the variable (categories) using breakpoint..Its equal to cat inside the done function, but once its gets out of the scope(done function), its value changes to undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I would say that you could use [session](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.session). Though in terms of design, a situation when you are passing a variable from one controller to another should be really questionable.

Answer (score 0):

In your CalendarController.js:

```
module.exports = {

foo: function(req, res, next) {

    User.findOne(2).exec(function(err, user) {

        if (err) return next(err);

        res.json(user);

    });
},


/**
 * Overrides for the settings in `config/controllers.js`
 * (specific to CalendarController)
 */
_config: {}

};
```

Comment: @Johngait We are again searching the object in the controller. How can we store the result into a variable and pass this into the another controller.